# Custom global error handler not hit when http error response is re-thrown by rxjs throwError

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-http-interceptors, zone.js

**Aim:** to have a global error handler for server errors and app errors (produced in Typescript code).

**How:** providing a custom ErrorHandler from a lib project inside the same workspace. This is my lib structure:

[image: @common/error-handling lib]

I have following http-interceptor (http-error.interceptor.ts)

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(@Inject(LOGGER_SERVICE) private logger: ILoggerService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(
        catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log('error');

          return throwError(error);
        })
    );
  }
}
```

The following custom global error handler (errors-handler.ts):

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    handleError(error: any): void {
        console.log('hi!');
    }

}
```

And this is the error-handling.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from './http-error.interceptor';
import { ErrorsHandler } from './errors-handler';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
      ],
      exports: [],
      providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorsHandler},
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true}
      ]
    })
    export class ErrorHandlingModule { }
```

In my public_api.ts file I only export the module

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of error-handling
 */

export * from './lib/error-handling.module';
```

In the same workspace I have an app (the default app provided by Angular CLI, it is not inside projects folder). In my app.module.ts I have imported the ErrorHandlingModule :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ErrorHandlingModule } from '@common/error-handling';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,

    ErrorHandlingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have already built my @common/error-handling lib.
I also have a fake api with json-server in which I have defined a "categories" end point. I call that service on app.component.ts in the onInit method, producing a 404 http error response by calling to the endpoint "categorie" (without "s"). I have the following in the console when I serve my app:

[image: Error shown in console, but not catched by global error handler]

The 404 error is there, I can also see the "error" log from http-error.interceptor.ts, but I cannot see the "hi!" log from my custom ErrorHandler.

The global error handler is working when I throw an error from app.component.ts after calling the fake api endpoint. Somehow, the line

```
return throwError(error);
```

in http-error.interceptor.ts is not reaching my global error handler.

Is it something related to zone.js? The error is thrown there and not bubbled up to the rest of the app. I am not so familiar with zone.js.

Any other thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Max.

Comment: When I throw error from Interceptor ErrorHandler can not catch it why?

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan I do not understand your question. Could you please reformulate it?

Comment: You have this statement : "return throwError(error);" in HttpErrorInterceptor class.
Should "ErrorsHandler" catch that?

Answer (score 4):

```
export class ErrorHandlingModule { 
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ErrorHandlingModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorsHandler},
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true} ]
    };
}
```

and then in the AppModule import with `ErrorHandlingModule.forRoot()`

For extra info - https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forRoot

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem was really stupid. I had a class that used as a base service (all services inherited from this base service), and there I had a catchError to return default values on error. Since this was the last catch of the chain, I was not hitting the global error handler.
Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for answering again!

Answer (score 1):

If your observable takes a callback for the error, the throwError operator will be returned to the observer and will not be picked up by the global error interceptor.

> Just comment the catchError block in subscribe

```
getWorkData(id: string): void {
this.userDataService.getWorkData(id).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.Id = response.Id;
    this.localStorage.setItem('WorkData', response);
  }
  // (err) => {
  //   //this.monitoringService.logException(err);
  // },
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found @avramz's answer helpful. I just want to provide a more complete example of what I did.

Bootstrap code

```
providers: [...,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: HttpErrorInterceptorService,
    multi: true,
  },
]
```

Service code

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HttpErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    readonly matSnackbar: MatSnackBar,
  ) {
  }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        this.matSnackbar.showErrorUnexpected(`Something unexpected happened (${e.status})`);
        return throwError(() => e);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```